# QGIS for multiple users

Tags: qgis

I've been using QGIS for several years on my PC to map our community fibre optic broadband network.  That's worked really well, but there are now two other people on the team who need to update the maps produced.

What's the best way to do this?

- I've experimented with QGIS Server - managed to publish the demonstration map to a web page but I've not worked out to edit this (everything I've read seems to suggest that QGIS Server is just to publish maps that have been generated in the desktop version)
- I could put the QGIS files on a shared directory (One Drive) and then set up each PC to use these files (although we risk corruption if two people have the project open at the same time)
- We share the PC...

This seems like such an common use case that I'm surprised I've not found the answer yet!

Comment: We uploaded our data to a local server and everyone has access to it. Parallel editing is circumvented by communication (in the few cases of the possibility).

Comment: Look for WFS and wfs-t

Comment: Using a PostGIS database? Using QGIS cloud? https://qgiscloud.com/

Comment: maybe using the qgis plugin mergin maps is the solution to your problem